# Does anything gets written to disk when doing a DLL injection?

Tags: injection

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection

**My question**: When someone is doing a DLL injection does anything gets written to disk? Or the whole attack is just in Memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DLL injection is a technique used for running code within the address space of another process by forcing it to load a dynamic-link library.

Address space is in Memory.

Now that's not to say that nothing will get written to disk. I could modify an executable in such a way that it loads xyz.dll on load. On the flip side of things, I could run my own project to inject code into the program to force it to load xyz.dll without writing anything to disk.

So the answer here is ***it depends***.